# Novel that draws from Eastern European (Romanian?) folklore

Tags: story-identification, books

The story takes place in the mountains and features a female protagonist who hunts with a bow. It has mystical elements and I think the goddess Diana takes interest in her. I also (oddly) remember that she enjoyed eating whole roast chickens for dinner.

The book also has a concept of a wind that comes in a particular season and makes people act angrily or aggressively and the book has an appendix discussing the real-world occurrence of that phenomenon. I think it had something to do with ionization of molecules in the air.

I think the author was female and they were writing the story to explore a particular type of Balkan/Eastern European folklore (possibly Romanian?).